# To test this service using svcutil.exe

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

I want to test a service with svcutil.exe. The step is

```
svcutil.exe http://11.55.99.341/MessagingServices/MessageData.svc?wsdl
```

I found that there is a cs file was generated in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin.

Some of code is likely as:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.5466
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MessagingAPI.Objects
{
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="InboxDTO", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MessagingAPI.Objects")]
public partial class InboxDTO : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    private System.Guid[] FullInboxField;

    private System.Guid InmateIdField;

    private int MessagesInWaitField;

    private int ReadMessagesField;

    private System.Guid[] UnreadInboxField;

    private int UnreadMessagesField;

    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Guid[] FullInbox
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FullInboxField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FullInboxField = value;
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to test it with this service with the code then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would either need to create an application that consumes this generated class -or- use the WcfTestClient application included with Visual Studio (which can be opened with the Visual Studio Command Prompt or can typically be found under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE [depending on your version of Visual Studio]).

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

Comment: It is unclear, suppose the generated cs is generatedClient.cs. It is already a client class?

Comment: Yes it's a class, but you'd still need to instantiate it. Right now you have a "blueprint" -- you need to put it to use!

Answer (score 4):

wgraham,'s answer is correct. To use the WcfTestClient

1. Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
2. File --> Add Service
3. Enter `http://11.55.99.341/MessagingServices/MessageData.svc`

Answer (score 1):

when you run svcutil.exe with the service URL its gonna give you a proxy class and a config file, u can add the class and the config file in a windows/web application and create an object of proxy class and start using the methods exposed as part of service.

Comment: I haven't found the config file. Only one class was generated. Do you have a sample to use svcutil.exe?